# "Après discussion[s]" - Peut-on accorder?

Tags: expressions, accord

#### Contexte

Je cherchais à employer *"Après discussion"* dans un mail et j'ai eu envie d'accorder ce nom commun puisque j'ai en effet eu de nombreuses discussions avant de pouvoir conclure le sujet et envoyer la décision prise.

#### Ngram

J'ai pu constater que *"Après discussions"* a été employé, [peu](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apr%C3%A8s%20discussion%2Capr%C3%A8s%20discussions&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capr%C3%A8s%20discussion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capr%C3%A8s%20discussions%3B%2Cc0) mais employé tout de même.

#### discussion n.f.

Le sens de [discussion](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/discussion) qui m'intéresse est ici :

> 1. Action de discuter.
>
>    - > Cette thèse admet deux modes de discussion entre lesquels nous avons à choisir.
>    - > Quant aux discussions philosophiques, je pense qu’elles sont absolument vaines.

Et [discuter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/discuter)

> discuter
>
> 1. Examiner, débattre avec quelqu’un **une** question, une affaire avec soin, avec exactitude, et en bien considérer le pour et le contre.

Il me semble donc que si j'ai débattu de plusieurs questions, j'ai eu plusieurs discussions, et donc je peux employer *"Après discussion**s**"*.

#### Expression

De là, il se pourrait que ce soit une expression dont la forme est fixe, ou pourrait-on l'accorder en fonction du nombre de discussions ?

> Après discussion avec Marc, on est parvenu à trouver un compromis.
>
> Après discussions avec Marc sur la température, Albert sur les dépenses et Simon sur les monuments, on a pu se décider sur notre destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Il me semble donc que si j'ai débattu de plusieurs questions, j'ai eu plusieurs discussions, et donc je peux employer "Après discussions".

Tout à fait. **Après discussions** peut renvoyer à plusieurs échanges avec une seule et même personne ou à un échange unique entre plusieurs personnes.  Dans le contexte que tu décris, où il s'agit de plusieurs échanges ayant eu lieu à divers moments avec différents interlocuteurs le pluriel s'impose.   Soit ton propos est assez contextualisé pour indiquer qu'il y a eu plusieurs discussions entre différentes parties et ne pas mettre « discussions » au pluriel serait une erreur. Soit le contexte ne rend pas la multiplicité des discussions et mettre « discussion » au singulier ne rend pas compte de la réalité et induit ton lecteur en erreur.

**Après discussions** est fréquemment employé dans le langage juridique :

> Quand il apparaît à l'auditorat qu'après discussions ultérieures une transaction est possible, et après avoir pris connaissance des documents et renseignements ...  ([Obligations, contrats et réparation des dommages: Les codes](http://bit.ly/2fzMXCQ))

Le contexte qui précède montre qu'il s'agit de plusieurs discussions entre différentes parties.

Voir aussi [*Procés-verbaux du Conseil d'État: contenant la discussion du projet de Code civil : ans IX-[XII], Volume 5*](http://bit.ly/2eELidj)

Plus proche d'un usage courant, on peut regarder dans la presse les négociations syndicales ou politiques.

> Éboueurs : après discussions, le travail reprend partiellement ([La Dépêche du midi du 16/10/2015](http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2015/10/16/2198925-eboueurs-apres-discussions-le-travail-reprend-partiellement.html))

Si l'article est centré sur une seule rencontre, il évoque d'autres discussions préalables qui justifient le pluriel du titre.

> Après discussions avec Bercy, le budget devrait s’établir à 32,7 milliards d’euros. [Le Monde 07/09/2016](http://www.lemonde.fr/politique/article/2016/09/07/budget-de-la-defense-une-rallonge-de-418-millions-d-euros-pour-2017_4993798_823448.html))

Le corps de l'article montre qu'il y a eu des discussions multiples avec divers interlocuteurs.

On peut aussi trouver « après discussions » dans le domaine romanesque :

> Après discussions, sondages, ils me proposent tous un deal. Classique. - Fais ton université, dit mon père, après quoi tu seras compositeur si tu le veux.  ([*Une semaine bien remplie*](http://bit.ly/2elIvua), Jacques Guyonnet)

dans un contexte familial où il apparaît qu'il y a eu plusieurs discussions entre les parents du héros et plusieurs de leurs connaissances.

> Après discussions, pesant le pour et le contre, elle n'est plus aussi négative sur le sujet. Cela peut marcher. ([*Pénélope... Plus jamais !*](http://bit.ly/2fzQMba) Marie Malassis)

Dans ce cas il s'agit de discussions ayant eu lieu entre deux personnes à diverses reprises.

Si on veut insister sur le fait qu'il y a eu plusieurs discussions on peut ajouter plusieurs (« après plusieurs discussions ») mais ceci ne s'impose pas du tout, le **s** à discussion est suffisant pour indiquer qu'il y en a eu plusieurs.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse, je n'aime pas trop les journaux en général, puisqu'ils présentent souvent des fautes, mais les autres sources me paraissent très justes.

Comment: @YohannV. Ça dépend quels journaux...  j'ai fait le tri et gardé que ce que je pense bien rédigé. Et pas de sources  non européennes ou québécoises,  elles abondent mais le français en est souvent de piètre qualité. Le terme discussions au pluriel est fréquent dans la presse syndicale mais je n'ai pas voulu non plus citer la presse syndicale car la qualité du français n'est pas souvent dans leurs objectifs;

Answer (score 5):

Mon avis personnel, basé sur aucune source ni recherche, est que ça *ne peut pas être faux* de le mettre au pluriel. C'est du français correct, je ne verrais pas le problème. Ça voudrait simplement dire "après plusieurs discussions".

La version au singulier est bien sûr plus idiomatique et représente bien un schéma de *désaccord → discussion → décision* par rapport à un problème précis.

Pour ma part, sans plus de contexte, j'utiliserais *après plusieurs discussions*, *après moult discussions*, *après de nombreuses discussions*.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense qu'une discussion peut inclure plusieurs questions, il n'y a pas  lieu de dire "après discussions".

Je n'ai pas de problème avec le pluriel de "discussion" mais dans le cas de la locution "après discussion", même si la discussion a lieu sur plusieurs jours, je considère ça comme "*une* discussion".

"Après discussion" (selon moi) implique qu'on a discuté de sujets différents, et qu'on a obtenu plusieurs décisions finales sur ces différents sujets. Si la totalité des discussions aboutit à une seule conclusion, j'utiliserais le singulier.

Il y a peut-être des cas précis et anecdotiques où il est plus adaptés d'utiliser le pluriel mais dans les cas courants, je pense qu'il est plus correct de se contenter du singulier.

Comment: Je ne l'ai peut être pas bien exprimé mais il s'agissait de plusieurs conversations avec des personnes différentes, dans différents lieux et non d'une grosse réunion traitant de plusieurs questions. (J'ai utilisé le singulier, mais j'ai eu envie de rajouter un 's' !)